# How to exclude people who selected (None) answer from the statsitics for the other two questions?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following database design:

```
Answers Table: AnswerID, Answer
QuestionAnswers Table: ID, QuestionID, AnswerID
CompleteSurvey Table: ID, QuestionAnswersID, RespondantID
Questions Table: QuestionID, Question
Employee Table: EmployeeID, Name
```

In one of the questions, I have the following answers:

```
ER Estimate
Company Esitmate
Both ER & Company Estimates
None
```

The answer of this question will affect two questions. What I want now, is to exclude the employees who selected (None) and then exclude them from number of participants in the other two questions. `So how to do that?`
Let us assume that we have three questions which are A, B and C. So how am I going to be able to exclude the people who selected (None) as an answer for question A from the number of employees who participated in Question B and C.

I wrote the query that shows me the number of participants in each possible answer for each question and it works well, but how I can improve it to get what I want above:

```
SELECT     COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.CompleteSurvey.RespondantID) AS [Total Number of Participants], dbo.Answers.Answer, dbo.Questions.Question
FROM         dbo.Questions INNER JOIN
                      dbo.QuestionsAnswers ON dbo.Questions.QuestionID = dbo.QuestionsAnswers.QuestionID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Answers ON dbo.QuestionsAnswers.AnswerID = dbo.Answers.AnswerID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.CompleteSurvey ON dbo.QuestionsAnswers.ID = dbo.CompleteSurvey.QuestionsAnswersID
GROUP BY dbo.Answers.Answer, dbo.Questions.Question
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
148 Both ER & Company Estimates
102 Company Estimate
22  ER Estimate  
130 None
```

The number of participants in each possible answer for Question A. Now for Question B, let us assume we have the following answers and number of participants:

```
22    Answer A
180   Answer B
180   Answer C
20    Answer D
```

When I applied you query to exclude the people with (None) answer in Question A from the following questions, I got negatives numbers for the all answers in Question B. How it can be like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this might work:

```
SELECT c.Answer, a.Question, COUNT(DISTINCT d.RespondantID) AS totalcount
FROM Questions a
INNER JOIN QuestionAnswers b ON a.QuestionID = b.QuestionID
INNER JOIN Answers c ON b.AnswerID = c.AnswerID
LEFT JOIN CompleteSurvey d ON b.ID = d.QuestionAnswersID
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT RespondantID
    FROM CompleteSurvey
    WHERE QuestionAnswersID IN (<id>, <id>)
) e ON d.RespondantID = e.RespondantID
WHERE e.RespondantID IS NULL
GROUP BY c.Answer, a.Question
```

You will have to know beforehand the `ID` for the question-answer combination you want to exclude, and insert it where it says `<id>` in the query.

Comment: Could you please explain to me what you mean by (a) and (b) in your query? Because I am thinking to use this query for different questions with the same issue

Comment: @TechLover Those are simply table references (It's a whole lot more succinct rather than typing out the whole database and table name for each field). All you would need to be concerned about is changing the `<id>`.

Comment: the problem that I have the total. Which means now with your query; if I have more than one QuestionAnswersID. If I applied one of them, then applied the other one, I will lose the results generated from applying the first ID. So How I can apply all of them to have one result at the end

Comment: @TechLover, I think what you're getting at is that you want to exclude employees who answered *multiple* question-answer combinations. See my updated answer where we use `IN ()`. Also note the `DISTINCT` added to the `COUNT()` in the `CROSS JOIN` since we don't want to count employees more than once.

Comment: @TechLover, see my revised solution. This time, I'm using a `LEFT JOIN` technique to exclude the employees who answered a particular set of question-answer combinations. Let me know how it works.

Comment: it works well now. Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @TechLover Awesome! Glad to hear that, and it was my pleasure. =)